# teamcity-agent Agent has unregistered (will upgrade)

Tags: docker, teamcity, docker-compose

The same `docker-compose.yml` file, the system is centos7 and root account

The normal container file permissions is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzASh.png)

but the normal container file permissions is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWMD5.png)

why the file permissions is `??????????? ? ?`
how can i fix it?

here is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "2.0"
services:
  teamcity-server:
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-server
    container_name: teamcity-server
    volumes:
      - /mnt/wmm/teamcity_server:/data/teamcity_server/datadir
      - /mnt/wmm/teamcity_server/logs:/opt/teamcity/logs
    ports:
      - "8111:8111"
    expose:
      - "8111"
  teamcity-agent:
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-minimal-agent
    environment:
      - SERVER_URL=teamcity-server:8111
    volumes:
      - /mnt/wmm/teamcity_agent:/data/teamcity_agent/conf
    container_name: teamcity-agent
    links:
      - teamcity-server
    depends_on:
      - teamcity-server
```

Comment: Might be the image has got corrupted? Delete the image and pull it again and see if it helps?

Comment: I've tried it many times,but not work

Comment: Uninstall docker and delete the docker data using `rm -rf /var/lib/docker` and reinstall docker, see if that is of any help